# MPMoviePlayerController removes top most view when done

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

I've got the following method to play a video from a shared application

```
    public async void Play(string url, string mimeType)
    {
        var videoPath = new NSUrl(url);
        var player = new MPMoviePlayerController(videoPath);

        player.AllowsAirPlay = true;
        player.SetFullscreen(true, true);
        player.ControlStyle = MPMovieControlStyle.Fullscreen;
        player.PrepareToPlay();

        do
        {
            await Task.Delay(100);
        } while (!player.IsPreparedToPlay);

        player.Play();
    }
```

The problem I have is that when the video is finished, it removes the top most view (Pops).

What I need is for the video to disappear and return the user to where they left off.

I came up with this work-around, but I know it's far from correct, and it does leave the player in view after exiting full screen (for just a moment).

```
    public async void Play(string url, string mimeType)
    {
        var videoPath = new NSUrl(url);
        var player = new MPMoviePlayerController(videoPath);

        var root = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.View;
        root.AddSubview(player.View);

        player.AllowsAirPlay = true;
        player.SetFullscreen(true, true);
        player.ControlStyle = MPMovieControlStyle.Fullscreen;
        player.PrepareToPlay();
        player.View.Frame = root.Bounds;

        var fakeView = new UIView { Frame = root.Bounds, BackgroundColor = UIColor.White };
        fakeView.AddSubview(player.View);

        do
        {
            await Task.Delay(100);
        } while (!player.IsPreparedToPlay);

        player.Play();
    }
```

It feels dirty to add the player to a subview twice. What would be the correct way to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

I have just added your code to my XF app (as needed a video player) and I don't get any pop when the video player closes so maybe something setup in your app causing the issue.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. Yes the code works, the issue is when there is a pushed view. The second code block works but is a real hack... I'm looking for a better solution.